# I am seeing no test run after running Nunit project on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: nunit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFr4V.png)

I have created a simple test project using dotnet c#. But unable to run the test in test explorer.
Also I am not seeing any exception thrown to me .I am using visual studio 2019

Comment: "solution explorer"? Do you mean "test explorer"?

Comment: And what do you mean by "unable"? Are your tests not shown in the test explorer? Or is the Run button disabled? Or is no test result shown?

Comment: I am able to see the run test button it is also enabled. But as soon I clicks .I see test not run in the test explorer. I have attached a screenshot

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Is there anything useful written to the output window?

Comment: Please show us the csproj file you have.

Comment: `<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>New_Project</RootNamespace>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.141.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>`